# await Backbone.Collection.fetch() does not wait

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, async-await, es6-promise

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fhcbeonz/)

testcase.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title />
        <script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
        <script src="underscore-1.8.3.js"></script>
        <script src="backbone-1.3.3.js"></script>
        <script src="testcase.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body />
</html>
```

---

testcase.js

```
class My_Collection extends Backbone.Collection {}
class My_View extends Backbone.View {
    async initialize() {
        let collection = new My_Collection;
        collection.url = 'http://backgridjs.com/examples/territories.json';
        console.log(collection);
        await collection.fetch();
        console.log(collection);
        $.extend(this, {collection});
        return this;
    }
    render() {
        console.log('render→→→', Date.now(), this.collection);
        this.collection.map(foo => foo);
    }
}

const view = new My_View;
view.render();
```

---

Result is

```
testcase.js:13:9 Object { length: 1, models: Array[1], _byId: Object, url: "http://backgridjs.com/examples/terr…" }
testcase.js:21:9 render→→→ 1494928366647 undefined
testcase.js:22:9 TypeError: this.collection is undefined
testcase.js:16:9 Object { length: 242, models: Array[242], _byId: Object, url: "http://backgridjs.com/examples/terr…" }
```

Note the out of order execution despite `await`. [`Collection.fetch()` is documented to return](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) a [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) which implements Promise.

I expect execution to wait on fetch(), attach the collection data to the view, and render to not crash on an undefined value. I can't see where it goes wrong. What does the correct code look like to make it work as intended?

Comment: I take it whatever calls initialize expects it to return a promise and waits for it to resolve (using await or .then) before continuing ... right?

Comment: @JaromandaX No it doesn't...

Comment: `$.extend(this, {collection});` Why are you using jQuery's `extend` for a simple assignation?

Comment: Emile B: because this is a [simplification](http://sscce.org) of the real code, which had a multiple assignment in this place. Ignore this, it's not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Note the following:

```
async initialize() {
```

You made the `initialize` asynchronous, now there is no guarantee that when you invoke `view.render();` `initialize` finished execution. You'll have to access the promise returned by `async initialize()` and invoke `render` once it's resolved which I'm not sure if possible with backbone because even the 1.3.3 source (latest release afaik) looks like this:

```
var View = Backbone.View = function(options) {
  this.cid = _.uniqueId('view');
  _.extend(this, _.pick(options, viewOptions));
  this._ensureElement();
  this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
  // ^----- Does not return the promise,
  // and shouldn't because this is supposed to be a constructor
};
```

---

You'll be better of with the old fashioned

```
collection.fetch().then(this.render.bind(this));
```

Why not use the promise that is already available?

Comment: You should use the `context` option with `fetch` so `render` gets called with the right context.

Comment: `then(this.render)` passes `render` as a reference without the context. `this` inside of render won't point to the view instance when the collection's promise will resolve. `fetch({context: this, success: this.render })` would work.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Yes that is correct there is many ways to get around this, `context`, `bind`, or arrow function since he is using es6 I'm having trouble choosing one :D

Comment: *> Why not use the promise that is already available?* Because I don't want to render at object construction and initialisation time. That's the responsibility of a different piece of code, that's why it needs to be separate. Is there no way to simply wait until the fetch promise is resolved?

Comment: @daxim call `view.collection.fetch({ /*...*/ })` in the responsible object instead of in the `initialize`. Or just attach a listener on the collection in the responsible object.

Comment: @daxim What Emile suggested above, you can even put that in a method like `{loadDataAndRender: function(){ this.collection.fetch({ /*...*/ }) }}` and call it from the other object like `view.loadDataAndRender();` instead of initialization... My question was why use `await` keyword instead of the available promise :)